# IE takes a part of string, reverses it and appends it to the beginning of the string

Tags: html, css

***Background***: I have an ExtJs application and it takes a few seconds to load, as it's a big application, so I decided to add a spinner to the `index.html` page and remove it on the app load.

Everything works as expected. The IE shows the correct text at first:

[image]

However, after a few milliseconds, it takes the last 4 characters, reverses it and appends it to the front (most probably after loading all the CSS and JavaScript of ExtJs framework and the app):

[image]

Crazy, eh? It works fine in Chrome; however, not in IE. Here is my code:

```
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Application</title>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style>
        .spinner_container{
            padding: 8px;
            background-color:#e5e5e5;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 15;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
        }
        .spinner_my_app{
            padding: 83px 0px 21px 17px;
            background-image: url('image_url');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position: center 0;
            color: #666666;
            font: normal 13px helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="spinner_container" id="page-loader">  
        <div class="spinner_my_app" id="spinner_text"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getSearchParameters() {
            //Get window parameters from query string and transform into an object
            return {lang: "en"};
        }

        var params = getSearchParameters();

        if(params["lang"]){
            if(params["lang"].indexOf('fr') > -1){
                document.getElementById("spinner_text").innerHTML += "Loading My Application(French Translation)...";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("spinner_text").innerHTML += "Loading My Application®...";
            }
        }else{
            document.getElementById("spinner_text").innerHTML += "Loading My Application®...";
        }
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I override this behavior?

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle, then make sure this is happening in the fiddle?

Comment: It looks like something is interpreting your page as being in a right-to-left script. Do you have any internationalisation going on, and have you tried adding `dir="ltr"` on the spinner text div for left-to-right languages? Or you could just add it to the html element.

Comment: @JacobGray I thought of that at first. However, it doesn't happen (locally) when the script tag for `microloader` is removed.

Comment: @RudiKershaw Wow, that was amazing! It worked. I'm using English and French; however, no other languages that are written right to left. Could you please help me dig deeper into this? And could you please post that as an answer as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Dumbledore - Glad I could help. I will see if I can figure out why your page is being incorrectly interpreted and I will edit it into my answer if I can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Rudi. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the positioning issues you describe (and show in your screenshots) when the text on a page is being incorrectly interpreted as 'right-to-left' instead of 'left-to-right'.

The `dir` attribute can be used to explicitly specify to the browser which type of script you intend. As an example you could do the following for your `spinner_container`;

```
<div class="spinner_container" id="page-loader">  
    <div dir="ltr" class="spinner_my_app" id="spinner_text"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you intend all content on the page to be left-to-right content you can just put the attribute in the `html` element like so;

```
<html dir="ltr" manifest="" lang="en-US">
```